# Does GCD main queue must have to be performed on the main thread?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am just curious is there anyway to use a different thread rather than the main thread for the main queue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of the main queue is to have it run on the main thread - the UI thread.

So no, there is no way to run the main queue on any other thread than the main thread.

Curious - why do you want the main queue on a different thread?

Comment: I am thinking if I have two main threads: sys main thread and anther main thread, such as rmaddy' main thread, so I can run two UI at the same time.

Comment: Can't be done. There is one main thread/main queue. All UI code is done on the one main thread.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't so much apply on iOS, but on OS X if you're writing a program which is not an application and does not run the run loop of the main thread, you can have some other thread call `dispatch_main()` and that thread will host the main queue. There's rarely a need to do this.

Comment: Nice, you are really knowledgable!